# How to get Firebase idToken from AuthResult?

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, apple-sign-in

Firebase are providing AuthResult on the callback for user sign in using startActivityForSignInWithProvider (in my case the provider is apple on Android platform).
I can't seem to fetch the idToken from it in a proper (synchronous) way.

So far I found two options, both aren't satisfying:

Option 1: casting

```
((OAuthCredential)authResult.getCredential()).getIdToken()
```

This works but I'm not sure if it's a safe cast. Plis, I'm thinking, if Firebase would have wanted us to fetch the idToken this way, they would have added it to AuthCredential.

Option 2: fetching it from the user

```
authResult.getUser().getIdToken(false).addOnCompleteListener { ... }
```

This seems to be a safe solution, but it's an async method. It doesn't seem to make sense to performing another async method, after the user just manually signed in (this is what i'm doing for an existing user).

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the asynchronous listener.  The reason for this is because the ID token will expire every hour, and your listener is how you know the very moment when the token has been refreshed, so you can start using that new token right away.

Comment: Thanks, guess that's what i'll be doing as long as there isn't any other option, but I still think it makes more sense to get it somewhere on the AuthResult, as it is a refreshed action that was just completed

Comment: It's not necessarily the case that an auth result requires a new ID token.  They are different events, which is why they're two different listeners.  They actually both used to be in the same listener, but that was problematic, so they split them apart like this.