# How to Authenticate with Firebase, Using Microsoft on Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

[Authenticate Using Microsoft on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/microsoft-oauth)

Originally, I was able to get to the auth page (see: [login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdvfA.png)), but then with no changes to the code, it seems to suddenly skip or fail at the `OnSuccessListener` function, which results in the auth page eventually failing and bringing me back to my home page in `MainActivity.java` [see: result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lRbI.png).

To be clear, I want the app I'm working with, to prompt a Microsoft sign-in and then upon success/failure, do something there. The Firebase Google-sign in works perfectly for me. I have a feeling that the problem may lie with how I'm redirecting the app from Firebase to Azure AD. If I click the first option (which I want), it still fails, and if I remove my URI entirely, I get an error message saying that I'm trying to authenticate with the wrong app [see: URI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAYZs.png).

ERROR: `com.google.firebase.auth.firebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException: The supplied auth credential is malformed or has expired. [Error getting access token from microsoft.com...]` [My app id, secret and redirect URI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfndP.png) all match what I have in my Azure AD. [ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGCWP.png)

```
        firebaseAuth
        .startActivityForSignInWithProvider(/* activity= */ this, provider.build())
        .addOnSuccessListener(
            new OnSuccessListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(AuthResult authResult) {
                // User is signed in.
                // IdP data available in
                // authResult.getAdditionalUserInfo().getProfile().
                // The OAuth access token can also be retrieved:
                // authResult.getCredential().getAccessToken().
                // The OAuth ID token can also be retrieved:
                // authResult.getCredential().getIdToken().
               // openActivity2();
                statusTextView.setText("Successfully authenticated with Microsoft.");
                microsoftSignOutButton.setVisibility(microsoftSignOutButton.VISIBLE);
            }
        })
        .addOnFailureListener(
            new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                // Handle failure.
                statusTextView.setText("Failed to load on Microsoft sign in.");
            }
        });
```

Comment: If the call fails, log the `Exception` you get to find out why that happened.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen it's telling me I have a `FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException`: The supplied auth credential is malformed or has expired: Error getting access token from microsoft.com, OAuth2 redirect uri is: (my given URI from Firebase ).

Comment: Please edit your question to include that information, by clicking the link under it. Hopefully somebody will be able to help when they see the error message. I'd also recommend searching for the error message, as this has popped up before.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen searching on google suggests that my input of auth credentials are potentially incorrect, but I verified everything :/ and still results as faulty.

Comment: I recently came across this entry which suggests that I need to cast `OAuthCredential` to my access token function (which I had commented out before). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60268077/how-to-get-firebase-idtoken-from-authresult The original issue still persists.

Comment: Found my issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62064249/firebase-authentication-to-azure-ad-from-android-app

Comment: Good to hear. I upvoted the accepted answer there, and marked yours as a duplicate to help folks in a similar situation find that solution.